# Groovy object tracking for binding

Tags: binding, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm developing a Groovy library providing variable binding/syncronization with simple syntax and rich event handler.
Firstly I'm aiming to archive running the following:

```
def a = 1 
def b = 1
def c = 1
a bind { b + c }
assert a==2 & b==1 & c==1
b = 3
assert a==4 & b==3 & c==1
c = -1
assert a==2 & b==3 & c==-1
```

I'd like avoid Java FX approach of providing additional classes but rather enhance objects with this functionality.

I'm stuck at finding some tracking of objects. Groovy doesn't feature overload of assignment expression. 
Currently I see solution in heavy AST transformation (maybe dsld might help).

Maybe there is some object tracking, events or whatever, I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you are writing your code using scripts. Did what you wanted with the following ideas:

- Instead of binding values to keys using the `Script.binding`, it is better if you create a `Variable` class which represents both the `value` and the variable `name`;
- Every method called on the `Variable` object gets delegated to its value;
- A `Listener` class which encapsulates a reference to the updating operation AND the `Variable` object which needs to be updated;
- An `updateListeners()` method, to, well, update the listeners;
- A `bind(closure)` method that just bypasses the closure to the variable object. It could pretty much be dropped and written as `a { b + c }`;

  ```
  class Listener { Closure operation; Variable variable }

  class Variable implements GroovyInterceptable { 
      String name; def value

      def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
          def var = args[0]
          var.class == Variable ? 
                  value."$method"(var.value) : value."$method"(var)
      }
  }

  Variable.metaClass.call = { Closure operation ->
      binding['listeners'] << 
              new Listener(operation: operation, variable: delegate)
      updateListeners()
  }

  def bind(Closure operation) { operation }

  def updateListeners() {
      binding.listeners.each {
          it.variable.value = it.operation()
      }
  }

  void setProperty(String prop, value) { 
      if (!binding.hasVariable('listeners')) binding['listeners'] = []
      binding[prop] = new Variable(name: prop, value: value)
      updateListeners()
  }
  ```

And your tests worked like a charm.

Comment: It seems I've confused you with my no-def, no-class variable declaration in the example.

Thanks for your ideas, I've learned some new Groovy features.
But still the question how to track local variables...

I've tried playing with closure but again - only binding variables appear.

Comment: Hm. So you want to be able to intercept variable creation in plain non-script groovy files?

Comment: Yes if it is possible.
Otherwise it seems that I should analyse code, find bind-like method invocations and inject additional code for variables taking part in binding.
Of course much easier to use SmthProperty explicitly like in JavaFX but my aim is to make things as simple as possible and require minimal re-factoring is case the lib would be added to existing code.

Comment: I doubt groovy can do that. Maybe you can intercept Object constructors using metaclass... Maybe you could benefit from annotations on variables, but that is java 8, i think

Comment: "is case the lib would be added to existing code", what about Groovy extensions?